# Algorithm for printing all accepted strings (to an upper bound if infinite amount) from a given DFA

Tags: java, graph-algorithm, regular-language, automata, finite-automata

As the title states I'm trying to write an algorithm that generates accepted strings to an upper bound from a given DFA (Deterministic Finite Automata) on input.

It should not generate more strings than the upper bound n if it contains cyclic patterns, because obviously I can't print an infinite amount of strings, which leads me to my problem.

Machines with finite languages are very straight forward as I can just do a DFS search and traverse through the graph and concatenate all letters that connect the states recursively, but I have no clue how I should deal with infinite language DFAs unless I hardcode a limit on how many times the DFS should traverse states that can potentially lead to cycles.

So my question is; how should go about approaching this problem. Are there any known algorithms that I could use to tackle this task?
the bound specifies the number of strings, not the length of them. The string length is not allowed to exceed 5000 characters, but should preferably not come near that in length, as the max bound, **n**, is 1000 at most on the tests.

My current and very naive solution is the following:

```
public void generateStrings(int currentStateNum, Set<String> output, String prefix, Set<Integer> traversedStates){

    State currentState, tempState;
    String nextString;
    currentState = dfa.get(currentStateNum);

    //keeps track of recursion track, i.e the states we've already been to.
    //not in use because once there are cyclic patterns the search terminates too quickly
    //traversedStates.add(currentStateNum);

    //My current, bad solution to avoid endless loops is by checking how many times we've already visited a state
    currentState.incrementVisited();


    //if we're currently looking at an accepted state we add the current string to our list of accepted strings
    if(currentState.acceptedState){
        output.add(prefix);
    }


    //Check all transitions from the current state by iterating through them.
    HashMap<Character, State> transitions = currentState.getTransitions();


    for (Map.Entry<Character, State> table : transitions.entrySet()) {

        //if we've reached the max count of strings, return, we're done.
        if (output.size() == maxCount) {
            return;
        }

        tempState = table.getValue();

        //new appended string. I realize stringbuilder is more efficient and I will switch to that
        //once core algorithm works
        nextString = prefix + table.getKey().toString();

        //my hardcoded limit, will now traverse through the same states as many times as there are states
        if (tempState.acceptedState || tempState.getVisitedCount() <= stateCount) {

            generateStrings(tempState.getStateNum(), output, nextString, traversedStates);

        }

    }


}
```

It is not really a dfs because I don't check which states I've already visited, because if I do that, everything that will be printed is the simplest path to the nearest accept state, which is not what I want. I want to generate as many strings as required (if the language for the DFA is not finite, that is).

This solution works up until a point where either the "visit limit" that I chose arbritarily no longer cuts it, so my solution is somewhat or entirely incorrect.

As you can see my datastructure for representing automata is an ArrayList with states, where State is a separate class that contains a HashMap with transitions, where the key is the edge char and the value is the state that the transition leads to.

Does anyone have any idea how I should proceed with this problem? I tried hard to find similar questions but I couldn't find anything helpful more than some github repos with code that is way too complicated for me to learn anything from.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Check this thread: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/

Comment: Is *stateCount* a constant? Cuz if you want to reuse one and the same character several times without repeating the same direction after coming again on it then you should consider duplicating by value nodes.

Comment: @dbl stateCount is indeed a constant, it's just the number of states in the current machine, I put it there because I wanted to see what happened, could just be whatever hardcoded limit. 

Even if I detect a cycle how should I go about handling it so I can still supply enough strings?

What does "duplicating by value nodes" mean, exactly?

Comment: Usually when implementing either bfs or dfs you will never visit one and the same node twice. For the purpose a boolean replication of the neighbourhood matrix is created and before visit a node u first check in the replica if the node is already visited -> if no then visit it and mark it in the replica as visited.

Comment: Yes, but now I will *have* to visit the same nodes several times, hence my question. If I avoid traversing cycles several times my output will not contain enough strings, hence my issue.

Comment: So instead of using a boolean visited replica u r counting the number of visits that has an upper bound? What I meant earlier is that if you visit the same node second time, path you will take from there will be exactly the same as it was during the first visit and then your string will look like [a1, a2...an...ak...an...ak...an] where the an...ak combination will be met *stateCount* times

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bounded queue of objects representing the current state and the string generated so far, and then proceed with something like the following,

1. Add {"", start} to the queue, representing the string created so far (which is empty) and the start state of the DFA.
2. As long as there is something on the queue

   1. Pop the front of queue
   2. If the current state is accepting, add the currentString to your result set.
   3. For each transition from this state, add entries to the queue of the form {currentString+nextCharacter, nextState}
3. Stop when you've hit enough strings, or if the strings are getting too long, or if the queue is empty (finite language).

Comment: Thanks, your pseudo code worked like a charm, except that it's way too slow when the boundary value approaches 1000.

Could that be because I don't use StringBuilder or because the approach is simply too slow? 
Could I exchange the while loop for a recursive call and expect faster computation? 

Thank you so much for taking your time!

Comment: When I try it out in the terminal with my example cases it's fast as hell, the automata it fails on is the one which describes all strings which has a length that is divisible by 7.